# Function create_function() deprecated

Tags: php

I'm using a plugin (wordpress) that is no longer supported. In php 7.1 it works well while with php 7.2, still works, but i get this error in 3 different files.

Could someone help me to fix it?

```
function GetChildFilesFast($recursive = false)
{
    static $parent_walker = false;
    if (!$parent_walker)
        $parent_walker = create_function('&$f,$fid,$pid', 'if($f->file_category != $pid) $f = null;');

    if ($this->is_file)
        return array($this->GetId() => $this);
```

---

```
$files = array_map(create_function('$fn', 'return substr($fn,' . strlen($dir) . ');'), list_files($dir));
    $result = array('dir' => $dir, 'files' => $files);
    return $result;
```

---

```
static function CreateTplFunc($parsed_tpl)
{
    return create_function('$f,$e=null', "return ($parsed_tpl);");
}
```

Many thanks!!

Andrea

Comment: As [the manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), that function was deprecated in PHP 7.2. So the solution is to not use it anymore and use [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know the problem and I studied it but I am not skilled in php. So i can't  fix the code...